# How to save and store data locally and on a server simultaneously in Swift?

Tags: android, firebase, core-data, realm

I am planning to make a mobile application for both iOS and Android. First, I would like to make the iOS version of the app. I am planning to use CoreData to save data locally when the mobile is not connected to the internet, then when the phone is connected to the internet, I would like to add the data (which is saved by the help of the CoreData) to the FireBase, then I would like to download all the data from the Firebase to the app to get the latest data. 
Is there any other solution to be able to save data offline and synchronize it to other platforms (in this case to Android) when the app is connected to the internet?

Comment: You can use JSONEncoder to save your data locally.

Comment: If you mean 'are there alternatives' to your planned strategy, check out Realm. It's not free, but I'm currently trying it out and I think it would do all of that work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already looking into Firebase, I'd suggest leveraging their [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) tool, as it handles everything from automatically syncing data between client and server, and leverages offline databases in case your users go offline and they have SDKs for iOS and Android.

Comment: The question is  "Is there any other solution to be able to save data offline"? Seems that OP doesn't want to use CoreData

Comment: @LeoDabus This answer is suggesting to use Firebase for the database *instead* of CoreData as it stores data online as well as offering [Offline Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) - so one stop shopping.